# Avoid task consumption for the get_activity_task function in AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-step-functions

I have a project that uses AWS services.

Basically there is a step-functions with a state which consists of an activity called "Process" whose work is performed by a worker in Python who polls every 5 minutes to know if there are tasks to do.
[image]

The worker code that looks for tasks to execute is:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(
    profile_name=config.profile_name,
    region_name=config.region_name
)
sfn_client = session.client("stepfunctions", config=Config(read_timeout=70))

task: dict = sfn_client.get_activity_task(activityArn=config.main_activity_arn)
```

and inside `task["input"]` the worker finds the information specific to the task to be executed.

Now I would like, using the information inside `task["input"]`, to decide whether to continue executing the task or leave it as if it was still to be executed.

The problem is that the `get_activity_task` function consumes the task token, so even returning the code immediately, a second worker execution no longer finds any task ready to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I suggest you have your worker call [SendTaskFailure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_SendTaskFailure.html)  with a specific error such as `Worker.Skip`. Then [you can specify retries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html#error-handling-retrying-after-an-error) with your Activity Task state to manage that as you would like (e.g. retry after 1 second, retry after a longer period, retry with exponential backoff, etc.).

But keep in mind that you will then receive this task again the next time you poll (or maybe not the next time, depending on how many other tasks you are sending via this Activity and how often you are polling. So if you want that specific task to take a different route, you might want to use [Catch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html#error-handling-fallback-states) to send it down a different path in your workflow.

Comment: Is there no possibility to get what I want without changing the structure of my state function, i.e. only changing the worker code?
The worker code can run on several machines, I'd like machine A to only take tasks of type A and so on, based on what is written inside `task["input"]`.